# ReportPortal installation on AWS EC2 and Integration with PyTest

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pytest, reportportal

I am trying to run **reportportal on my AWS EC2 instance** and connect it to my pytest framework.
I have followed the guide available at reportportal.io on installation.

[ReportPortal Installation Guide](https://reportportal.io/docs/Deploy-with-Docker)

[ReportPortal Pytest Integration](https://github.com/reportportal/agent-python-pytest)

**Locally I am able to get reportportal up and running and also able to log the test results.**

I am **able to access the reportportal running on AWS EC2 instance using browser** with the public IP(Elastic Ip) that is assigned to the EC2 instance.

I am also able to log the test results on the reportportal running on AWS EC2 using **SSH Tunneling**. Not able to understand what is the issue and why it fails to log directly using rp_uuid and other info taken from the reporportal instance running on AWS EC2.

If anyone has got it up and running successfully let me know what more config changes are needed or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `why it fails to log directly using the ACCESS_TOKEN.` - what exactly is it that you are doing here?

Comment: I have taken the rp_uuid and other specifications from the aws ec2 reportportal and copied them to pytest.ini file(replaced the local values) and trying to run, rp_uuid is the access token that i mentioned here